# Hidden JavaScript Payload

Tags: javascript

I found this javascript very strange, when I run on my console browser it gives me an alert with the following message

> 'Always be wary of Javascript containing quotes. No quotes = safe!'

I am very curious about it (really doesn't even know if this is a thing, is it useful for something?)

If any of you would like to share knowledge about this kind of "techniques" I will totally appreciate! :)

```js
for(A in {A:0}){alert(unescape(escape(A).replace(/u.{8}/g,[])))};
```

Comment: Is what useful?  JavaScript containing strings?

Comment: The hidden message, I mean, this can cause a lot of trouble for finding this code...

Comment: This may be interesting for you https://github.com/denysdovhan/wtfjs

Comment: There are plenty of ways of obfuscating code, problem is, it all needs to be read so at some point, it is assembled into something readable.

Comment: https://www.stefanjudis.com/blog/hidden-messages-in-javascript-property-names/  pretty good explanation of the code available there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explained in detail on this blog post: https://www.stefanjudis.com/blog/hidden-messages-in-javascript-property-names/

The main "trick" to this snippet is that there are lots of invisible unicode characters between the `{` and the `A` here:

```
{A:0}
```

You can see the code points for them like this:

```
Object.keys({A:0})[0].split("").map(x => x.codePointAt(0))
// [65, 56128, 56684, 56128, 56695, 56128, 56673, 56128, 56697, 56128, 56691, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56674, 56128, 56677, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56695, 56128, 56673, 56128, 56690, 56128, 56697, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56687, 56128, 56678, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56650, 56128, 56673, 56128, 56694, 56128, 56673, 56128, 56691, 56128, 56675, 56128, 56690, 56128, 56681, 56128, 56688, 56128, 56692, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56675, 56128, 56687, 56128, 56686, 56128, 56692, 56128, 56673, 56128, 56681, 56128, 56686, 56128, 56681, 56128, 56686, 56128, 56679, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56689, 56128, 56693, 56128, 56687, 56128, 56692, 56128, 56677, 56128, 56691, 56128, 56622, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56654, 56128, 56687, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56689, 56128, 56693, 56128, 56687, 56128, 56692, 56128, 56677, 56128, 56691, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56637, 56128, 56608, 56128, 56691, 56128, 56673, 56128, 56678, 56128, 56677, 56128, 56609]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can run below code to understand why you're getting `Always be wary of Javascript containing quotes. No quotes = safe!` in alert box -

> As what you see is not what it seems to be

```js
//for(A in {A:0}){alert(unescape(escape(A).replace(/u.{8}/g,[])))};

//Let's run this script in steps - copied from above only
var object = {A:0};

//get key of above object
var key = Object.keys(object)[0];

//get value of above object
var value = object[key];

//here key is not actual character A
console.log(key === "A");

//same case for value
console.log(value === 0);
```

Comment: whoever down-voted this answer, please explain the reason behind it so that I can improve this answer for better understanding